# git push -u origin master mistake

Tags: git, github

Ok, I guess this question is popular, but I just dint understand. I create a new repo on GitHub, then I go to my folder, where I have some code I do the next steps:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/MyNick/MyCode.git
git push -u origin master
```

And so I get:

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: use `git remote` instead of `git git remote`...

Comment: Take a look at dusual's answer, can you post your .git/config file? Also, as a suggestion, don't call your remotes `origin`, if you are going to work on more repositories it may become confusing, give them significant names. With git you can use aliases, so it is not going to be longer to write than the default `origin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `ssh` repo.

It is very likely that is something like

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:MyNick/MyCode.git
git push -u origin master
```

That should work well.

Comment: so, I've added a shh key, and all now everything working, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well the above answers should work . Another suggestion when in doubt check you .git/config file . It will give you most of the details related submodules/origin/branches you may need to know

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = xxx

[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master

[submodule "submodule"]
        url = xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have created the GitHub repository? The error message suggests it can't find a repo at the GitHub URL. You may have just faked it as an example, but I get a 404 error when I try to access https://github.com/MyNick/MyCode.git.