# Git Push and SSH key

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm having [THIS PROBLEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681189/git-push-u-origin-master-mistake)

I cannot set up an SSH Key to rectify the problem. I'm following [THESE STEPS](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) to set up an SSH key. When I get to:

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
```

I cannot enter a passphrase.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: When you enter a passphrase, it doesn't show up - this is for security reasons.  If you enter your passphrase and press enter, do you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "I cannot enter a passphrase", you mean that nothing is shown while you're typing in your passphrase, then there's no problem. You can simply type your passphrase, and then hit enter. Your passphrase should be asked twice.

If you've ever used `sudo` or `su`, you may remember that nothing is shown either.

Comment: that's great thanks. Now on my command line I have: "My-MacBook-Pro:.ssh ME$" and I cannot cd into any directory or "git push -u origin master" Sorry for the continued question

Comment: @user1910388 Simply typing `cd` should put you back into your `$HOME` directory. To `git push` you should get back into your local repository (the directory that holds your source code, it has a `.git` folder (use `ls -A` to show hidden files/directories.))

Answer (score 1):

Keep typing and press enter. It should work from there. On unix systems, by default, you just don't get any output when you type a password as this is more secure than showing obfuscated characters.